# Values in a list to a range()

Tags: python-3.x, list, range

I have a user input which comes in as follows:

```
j = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-6', '7-9']
```

I want to go through this list, identify any 'ranges' such as `7-8`, or `5-99` etc.

With these remove the `-` and put the first and second values into `range()`

So far I have the following, I just can't figure out how to get the values into the right place, perhaps I need to select the number before the `-` and after the `-` ?

```
        for item in j:
            if "-" in item:
                item = item.split("-")
                # list(map(str, range(244, 247)))
                for r in item:
                    print(r)
                    print('next')

                # something like this?
                list(map(str, range(int(item[0]), int(item[1]))))
```

EDIT

Taking into account jonrsharpe's comment:

```
        for item in j:
            if "-" in item:
                start, stop = item.split("-")
                print('start:' + start + ' end: ' + stop)
                list(map(str, range(int(start), int(stop))))
```

This returns a type error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: If it will only ever be `\d+` or `\d+-\d+`, in the case `"-" in item` why not `start, stop = item.split("-")`?

Comment: what is it that you want to accomplish? like, get a list from a range between 5 - 10?

Comment: What is the expected output? Should `j` be reduced to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output expected is `j = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

You can create a blank list, process each element depending on whether or not it has a "-"

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-6', '7-9']
ll = []
for element in l:
    if '-' in element:
        sublist = element.strip().split('-')
        sublist = list(range(int(sublist[0]), int(sublist[1]) + 1))
        ll += sublist
    else:
        ll.append(int(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a list of items for both single numbers and ranges, and then use this as the argument to `range`:

```
j = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5-6', '7-9']

for item in j:
    if '-' in item:
        rng = [int(x) for x in item.split('-')]
    else:
        # Start and stop are the same
        rng = [int(item)] * 2
    # Pad the stop number
    rng[1] += 1
    for i in range(*rng):
        print(i)
```